# Is 1/vector is a vector or not?

Tags: vectors

Let $\vec { A } = a \hat { i } + b \hat { j } + c \hat { k }$. Is $\frac { 1 } { \vec { A } }$ a vector or not, and if it is, then what are its components?"

Comment: The inverse (one over something) is closely related to multiplication. But for vectors, there is no simple (unique) definition of multiplication. Therefore, it's a little difficult to imagine what would be "one divided by a vector".

Comment: $\frac { 1 } { \vec { A } }$ is like "the square root of blue", i.e. meaningless.

Comment: How do you define $\frac{1}{\vec{A}}$?

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard definition of $\frac{1}{\boldsymbol{x}}$ where $\boldsymbol{x}$ is a vector. Therefore, the expression "$\frac{1}{\boldsymbol{x}}$" is generally meaningless (undefined), unless it is specifically defined in the context where it is used.